# Laravel 4 foreach loop - wanting to display the last element

Tags: loops, foreach, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently trying to set up an edit page where an order form is populated using json_decode to decode json information that was saved when the form was created. Because the form's size can change I have to create the correct number of inputs so that all the json data will have a place to be displayed. Fortunately as the inputs are numbered this should not be hard to do. Unfortunately I am not sure how to pick the last element of the json information that has been decoded. Currently I am using:

```
public function getEdit($id){
        $order = Order::where('id', '=', $id);

        if($order->count()) {
            $order                      = $order->first();
            $order->order_serialized    = json_decode($order->order_serialized);

            foreach($order->order_serialized as $key => $value){
                $order->$key = $value;
            }
            return View::make('orders.edit')
                    ->with('order', $order);
        }   else {
            return App::abort(404);
        }
    }
```

to decode the information and it is working splendidly but I need to be able to pick up the last element to be able to find the total number of inputs and am not sure how I could do this without disturbing the foreach loop. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `count` and `toArray` methods to find the last item.

```
$nItem = $order->count();
$aOrder = $order->toArray();
$aLastItem = $aOrder[$nItem-1];
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like its just what I was looking for.

Comment: Quick question - it says "Undefined offset: 6 " Any idea what this means?

Comment: are you sure that the indexes of the array are numbers and not column names? Undefined offset 6 means that it was looking for $aOrder[6] which doesn't exist

Comment: `var_dump($aOrder)` and see what the elements look like.  Not sure it matters too much though, ceejayoz has a much cleaner answer and I had not realized there was a `last()` method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that there were comments on this. I dd($aOrder) and saw that it had all the inputs listed which is great. I looked at dd($nItem) and noticed it was 7 even though there were more items than that, so I'll have to look at that later. But thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Collections have a `last()` function to compliment the `first()` function.

Comment: I tried using last() like this
foreach($order->order_serialized as $key => $value){
    $order->$key = $value;
    if($order->$key->last()){
     $last_element = $order->$key;
    } ;
   }
but the debug said I was trying to use it on a non-object.

Comment: not in the foreach loop , outside of it, like $order->last() is the last row of your $order object

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment earlier. This looks great. I just have a quick question. In my database all of the form's input is stored in a "order_serialized" row in json_encoded info. To get to it I was thinking of using:
`$order->order_serialized = json_decode($order->order_serialized);
$last_item     = $order->order_serialized->last();`

Comment: But that returns "Call to undefined method stdClass::last() ", any idea where I'm going wrong?